# Making Virtuemart product detail page accessible to public user

Tags: joomla-3.x, acl, virtuemart

Does anybody know that how can I enable a product detail page available to all public and registered users  where the virtue mart component is accesable to only registered users. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't built a VirtueMart site in a while but, the short answer is to make VirtueMart available to "public" and require registration before anything can be purchased. Again, working from memory, seems to me this is the most common way of working with VirtueMart.